# Flutter Riverpod: Refresh Page Offscreen using State Notifier

Tags: flutter, refresh, riverpod

I'm using StateNotifier and Riverpod.
I have a notification page, which contains a list of notification. When a notification arrives, I trigger a refresh for notification. However, when I navigate to notification page, it still using the old (cached?) list.

How do I refresh a page offscreen?

#### Foreground Message

```
FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
  _localNotification.showLocalNotification(message);
  ProviderContainer().read(notificationProvider).getNotification();
});
```

#### Background Message

```
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  final LocalNotification localNotification = LocalNotification();
  await localNotification.init();
  localNotification.showLocalNotification(message);
  ProviderContainer().read(notificationProvider).getNotification();
}
```

#### NotificationProvider

```
Future<void> getNotification() async {
  try {
    state = const NotificationLoadingState();
    _notificationList = await _notificationRepository.getNotification();
    state = NotificationLoadedState(_notificationList); // ==> I get a new list here
  } catch (e, s) {
    state = const NotificationErrorState('error fetching notification');
  }
}
```

#### UI

```
final state = watch(notificationProvider.state);
if (state is NotificationLoadingState) {
  return _buildLoading();
} else if (state is NotificationLoadedState) {
  return _buildLoaded(state.notificationList); // ==> I still get the old list here
} else if (state is NotificationErrorState) {
  return _buildError(state.message);
}
```

### Edit:

I managed to solve the foreground message handler by using `navigatorKey.currentContext`.

However, I still haven't solved background message handler.
I've tried changing my `main.dart` to use `UncontrolledProviderScope` with a global `ProviderContainer`, which then was called from background message handler. It's still not refreshing.

Answer (score 1):

With this line you are creating a new instance for your providers :

```
 ProviderContainer().read(notificationProvider).getNotification();
```

you need to use a context to get the existing instance of ProviderContainer:

```
context.read(notificationProvider).getNotification();
```

or if you are not inside ui make dependencies between your providers

Comment: You're right. I managed to refresh it by using `navigatorKey.currentContext`.
Do you have any sample on how to add dependencies between providers? Do you use `ProviderReference`? Since I'm still a bit lost on calling it from outside the UI. Do I not use `ProviderContainer` then?

Comment: I've tried changing my `main.dart` to use `UncontrolledProviderScope` with a global `ProviderContainer`, which said container is the one I called from background message handler. However, it's still not refreshing.

Comment: Use ProviderReference to add dependencies between providers. Can't help you more since i'm not familiar with firebase and streams. But your should create a Provider for your Firebase instance, a streamProvider for your on message stream and make your notificationProvider depend of itby calling ref.watch(streamProvider). So every time your stream emit a value your notification provider will be re-instancied with the new value